# Ordered list with random numbers between 1 and 49

Tags: javascript, php

I have some problems to Code an simple PHP ordered list that print out a random number list between 1 and 49.

The Main Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AJAX</title>
<meta name="viewport" content=
"width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="lib/css/stil.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"
src="lib/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Ziehung der Lottozahlen</h1>
<button id="frage">Starte die Ziehung</button>
<div id="antwort">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the external PHP Code to randomize the numbers

```
<?php
$zahlen = range (1, 49);
shuffle($zahlen);
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
echo $zahlen[$i] . " ";
 }
?>
```

And here the Java script

```
var resOb = new XMLHttpRequest();
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("frage").onclick = 
function () {
    resOb.open('get', 'lottozahlen1.php', true);
    resOb.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (resOb.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("antwort").innerHTML = 
            resOb.responseText;
}
    };
    resOb.send(null);
};
};
```

T
Now my question...how i can let Show the numbers in a ordered list?

Comment: what's the output currently u getting?

Comment: @Kool-Mind The Output is like this ( 22 34 14 10 23)

Comment: I Need it ordered with <ol> and <li>

Comment: Why randomise the numbers in the first place if you then want to reorder them??

Comment: @RamRaider I know, but i have to random the numbers with Output in a ordered list

Comment: @Marco please have a look on php code, hope u need that only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending [Kool-Mind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39012828/4485549):

> ```
> $zahlen = range (1, 49);
> ```

```
shuffle($zahlen);
$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
  $arr[$i] =$zahlen[$i] . " ";
}
sort($arr,1);
echo implode(' ',$arr);
```

Try adding the code below(to generate the list):

```
<script>
  $('#button').click(function(){
    $('#newDiv').append('<ol>');
    $('#newDiv').append('<?php foreach($arr as $a){echo"<li>".$a."";}?>');
    $('#newDiv').append('</ol>');
  })
</script>
```

Hope it helps =)

***EDIT***

This should be working fine now, hope it helps =)

```
<button id="button">Button</button>
<div id="newDiv"></div>

<script>
  var clicked = false;
  $('#button').click(function(){
    if (!clicked){
      <?php
      $arr = array();
      for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $arr[$i] = rand(1,49);
      }
      sort($arr,1);
    ?>
    $('#newDiv').append('<ol>');
    $('#newDiv').append('<?php foreach($arr as $a){echo"<li>".$a."";}?>');
    $('#newDiv').append('</ol>');
    clicked = true;
   }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: @Marco, add the script tag at the end of section of your html. (or anywhere else). It should get you working by joining my code and Kool-Mind's code

Comment: Please show me how. I add the script in my HTML but it don't works.

Comment: @Marco I've updated my answer, it might not be the best solution, but still hope my answer helps you =)

Answer (score 2):

use PHP code below way

```
$zahlen = range (1, 49);
shuffle($zahlen);
$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
$arr[$i] =$zahlen[$i] . " ";
 }
 sort($arr,1);
echo implode(' ',$arr);
```

Comment: The Output is the same.

Comment: No, with your Code the Output is the same like my first Code. I need a ol list with this numbers

Comment: @Marco do you have any typo in it? It works great for me

Comment: @HL96 Yes it works great for me too, but as you can see in my Main Code i have a button that must generate the list.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string, <strike>map the values as number and sort the array</strike>. Then generate the wanted list items and put it to the wanted unordered list.

```js
var lotto = '22 34 14 10 99',
    list = lotto
        .split(' ')
//        .map(Number)
//        .sort(function (a, b) {
//            return a - b;
//        })
        .reduce(function (list, a) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = a;
            list.appendChild(li);
            return list;
        }, document.createElement('ol'));

document.body.appendChild(list);
```

Comment: I suggest adding a function generating few random numbers and make it `ol` instead of `ul`, as per requested in the question. The rest works well. =)

Comment: i suppose, the numbers are generated outside (async) and they should be processed later.

Comment: @Nina Scholz Yes, exactly

Comment: @HL96 The Code works great. But the numbers between 1 and 49 are generated in a external php, and i need reference to the button id "frage"

Comment: you could move the assignment of list inside of the click callback.